# CodeIgniter + Community Auth redirect link auto insertion

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just installed [Community Auth](http://community-auth.com/) for Codeigniter module. I wonder how and why, when i want to get to the site `http://mylocalsite.dev/examples`

it automatically exchange page adress for:

```
http://mylocalsite.dev/login?redirect=examples
```

I can't find where is something which do it. Below I am presenting to You my whole examples controller:

```
/**
 * Community Auth - Examples Controller
 *
 * Community Auth is an open source authentication application for CodeIgniter 3
 *
 * @package     Community Auth
 * @author      Robert B Gottier
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2011 - 2016, Robert B Gottier. (http://brianswebdesign.com/)
 * @license     BSD - http://www.opensource.org/licenses/BSD-3-Clause
 * @link        http://community-auth.com
 */

class Examples extends MY_Controller
{
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Force SSL
    //$this->force_ssl();

    // Form and URL helpers always loaded (just for convenience)
    $this->load->helper('url');
    $this->load->helper('form');
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Demonstrate being redirected to login.
 * If you are logged in and request this method,
 * you'll see the message, otherwise you will be
 * shown the login form. Once login is achieved,
 * you will be redirected back to this method.
 */
public function index()
{
    if( $this->require_role('admin') )
    {
        echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

        echo '<p>You are logged in!</p>';

        echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * A basic page that shows verification that the user is logged in or not.
 * If the user is logged in, a link to "Logout" will be in the menu.
 * If they are not logged in, a link to "Login" will be in the menu.
 */
public function home()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

    echo '<p>Welcome Home</p>';

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Demonstrate an optional login.
 * Remember to add "examples/optional_login_test" to the
 * allowed_pages_for_login array in config/authentication.php.
 *
 * Notice that we are using verify_min_level to check if
 * a user is already logged in.
 */
public function optional_login_test()
{
    if( $this->verify_min_level(1) )
    {
        $page_content = '<p>Although not required, you are logged in!</p>';
    }
    elseif( $this->tokens->match && $this->optional_login() )
    {
        // Let Community Auth handle the login attempt ...
    }
    else
    {
        // Notice parameter set to TRUE, which designates this as an optional login
        $this->setup_login_form(TRUE);

        $page_content = '<p>You are not logged in, but can still see this page.</p>';

        // Form helper needed
        $this->load->helper('form');

        $page_content .= $this->load->view('examples/login_form', '', TRUE);
    }

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

    echo $page_content;

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Here we simply verify if a user is logged in, but
 * not enforcing authentication. The presence of auth 
 * related variables that are not empty indicates 
 * that somebody is logged in. Also showing how to 
 * get the contents of the HTTP user cookie.
 */
public function simple_verification()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

    echo '<p>';
    if( ! empty( $this->auth_role ) )
    {
        echo $this->auth_role . ' logged in!<br />
            User ID is ' . $this->auth_user_id . '<br />
            Auth level is ' . $this->auth_level . '<br />
            Username is ' . $this->auth_username;

        if( $http_user_cookie_contents = $this->input->cookie( config_item('http_user_cookie_name') ) )
        {
            $http_user_cookie_contents = unserialize( $http_user_cookie_contents );

            echo '<br />
                <pre>';

            print_r( $http_user_cookie_contents );

            echo '</pre>';
        }

        if( config_item('add_acl_query_to_auth_functions') && $this->acl )
        {
            echo '<br />
                <pre>';

            print_r( $this->acl );

            echo '</pre>';
        }

        /**
         * ACL usage doesn't require ACL be added to auth vars.
         * If query not performed during authentication, 
         * the acl_permits function will query the DB.
         */
        if( $this->acl_permits('general.secret_action') )
        {
            echo '<p>ACL permission grants action!</p>';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Nobody logged in.';
    }

    echo '</p>';

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Most minimal user creation. You will of course make your
 * own interface for adding users, and you may even let users
 * register and create their own accounts.
 *
 * The password used in the $user_data array needs to meet the
 * following default strength requirements:
 *   - Must be at least 8 characters long
 *   - Must be at less than 72 characters long
 *   - Must have at least one digit
 *   - Must have at least one lower case letter
 *   - Must have at least one upper case letter
 *   - Must not have any space, tab, or other whitespace characters
 *   - No backslash, apostrophe or quote chars are allowed
 */
public function create_user()
{
    // Customize this array for your user
    $user_data = [
        'username'   => 'test',
        'passwd'     => 'test',
        'email'      => 'osemka59@gmail.com',
        'auth_level' => '9', // 9 if you want to login @ examples/index.
    ];

    $this->is_logged_in();

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

    // Load resources
    $this->load->model('examples/examples_model');
    $this->load->model('examples/validation_callables');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_data( $user_data );

    $validation_rules = [
        [
            'field' => 'username',
            'label' => 'username',
            'rules' => 'max_length[12]|is_unique[' . config_item('user_table') . '.username]',
            'errors' => [
                'is_unique' => 'Username already in use.'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'field' => 'passwd',
            'label' => 'passwd',
            'rules' => [
                'trim',
                'required',
                [ 
                    '_check_password_strength', 
                    [ $this->validation_callables, '_check_password_strength' ] 
                ]
            ],
            'errors' => [
                'required' => 'The password field is required.'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'field'  => 'email',
            'label'  => 'email',
            'rules'  => 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[' . config_item('user_table') . '.email]',
            'errors' => [
                'is_unique' => 'Email address already in use.'
            ]
        ],
        [
            'field' => 'auth_level',
            'label' => 'auth_level',
            'rules' => 'required|integer|in_list[1,6,9]'
        ]
    ];

    $this->form_validation->set_rules( $validation_rules );

    if( $this->form_validation->run() )
    {
        $user_data['passwd']     = $this->authentication->hash_passwd($user_data['passwd']);
        $user_data['user_id']    = $this->examples_model->get_unused_id();
        $user_data['created_at'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        // If username is not used, it must be entered into the record as NULL
        if( empty( $user_data['username'] ) )
        {
            $user_data['username'] = NULL;
        }

        $this->db->set($user_data)
            ->insert(config_item('user_table'));

        if( $this->db->affected_rows() == 1 )
            echo '<h1>Congratulations</h1>' . '<p>User ' . $user_data['username'] . ' was created.</p>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<h1>User Creation Error(s)</h1>' . validation_errors();
    }

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * This login method only serves to redirect a user to a 
 * location once they have successfully logged in. It does
 * not attempt to confirm that the user has permission to 
 * be on the page they are being redirected to.
 */
public function login()
{
    // Method should not be directly accessible
    if( $this->uri->uri_string() == 'examples/login')
        show_404();

    if( strtolower( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] ) == 'post' )
        $this->require_min_level(1);

    $this->setup_login_form();

    $html = $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);
    $html .= $this->load->view('examples/login_form', '', TRUE);
    $html .= $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);

    echo $html;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Log out
 */
public function logout()
{
    $this->authentication->logout();

    // Set redirect protocol
    $redirect_protocol = USE_SSL ? 'https' : NULL;

    redirect( site_url( LOGIN_PAGE . '?logout=1', $redirect_protocol ) );
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * User recovery form
 */
public function recover()
{
    // Load resources
    $this->load->model('examples/examples_model');

    /// If IP or posted email is on hold, display message
    if( $on_hold = $this->authentication->current_hold_status( TRUE ) )
    {
        $view_data['disabled'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // If the form post looks good
        if( $this->tokens->match && $this->input->post('email') )
        {
            if( $user_data = $this->examples_model->get_recovery_data( $this->input->post('email') ) )
            {
                // Check if user is banned
                if( $user_data->banned == '1' )
                {
                    // Log an error if banned
                    $this->authentication->log_error( $this->input->post('email', TRUE ) );

                    // Show special message for banned user
                    $view_data['banned'] = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    /**
                     * Use the authentication libraries salt generator for a random string
                     * that will be hashed and stored as the password recovery key.
                     * Method is called 4 times for a 88 character string, and then
                     * trimmed to 72 characters
                     */
                    $recovery_code = substr( $this->authentication->random_salt() 
                        . $this->authentication->random_salt() 
                        . $this->authentication->random_salt() 
                        . $this->authentication->random_salt(), 0, 72 );

                    // Update user record with recovery code and time
                    $this->examples_model->update_user_raw_data(
                        $user_data->user_id,
                        [
                            'passwd_recovery_code' => $this->authentication->hash_passwd($recovery_code),
                            'passwd_recovery_date' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s')
                        ]
                    );

                    // Set the link protocol
                    $link_protocol = USE_SSL ? 'https' : NULL;

                    // Set URI of link
                    $link_uri = 'examples/recovery_verification/' . $user_data->user_id . '/' . $recovery_code;

                    $view_data['special_link'] = anchor( 
                        site_url( $link_uri, $link_protocol ), 
                        site_url( $link_uri, $link_protocol ), 
                        'target ="_blank"' 
                    );

                    $view_data['confirmation'] = 1;
                }
            }

            // There was no match, log an error, and display a message
            else
            {
                // Log the error
                $this->authentication->log_error( $this->input->post('email', TRUE ) );

                $view_data['no_match'] = 1;
            }
        }
    }

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

    echo $this->load->view('examples/recover_form', ( isset( $view_data ) ) ? $view_data : '', TRUE );

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Verification of a user by email for recovery
 * 
 * @param  int     the user ID
 * @param  string  the passwd recovery code
 */
public function recovery_verification( $user_id = '', $recovery_code = '' )
{
    /// If IP is on hold, display message
    if( $on_hold = $this->authentication->current_hold_status( TRUE ) )
    {
        $view_data['disabled'] = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        // Load resources
        $this->load->model('examples/examples_model');

        if( 
            /**
             * Make sure that $user_id is a number and less 
             * than or equal to 10 characters long
             */
            is_numeric( $user_id ) && strlen( $user_id ) <= 10 &&

            /**
             * Make sure that $recovery code is exactly 72 characters long
             */
            strlen( $recovery_code ) == 72 &&

            /**
             * Try to get a hashed password recovery 
             * code and user salt for the user.
             */
            $recovery_data = $this->examples_model->get_recovery_verification_data( $user_id ) )
        {
            /**
             * Check that the recovery code from the 
             * email matches the hashed recovery code.
             */
            if( $recovery_data->passwd_recovery_code == $this->authentication->check_passwd( $recovery_data->passwd_recovery_code, $recovery_code ) )
            {
                $view_data['user_id']       = $user_id;
                $view_data['username']     = $recovery_data->username;
                $view_data['recovery_code'] = $recovery_data->passwd_recovery_code;
            }

            // Link is bad so show message
            else
            {
                $view_data['recovery_error'] = 1;

                // Log an error
                $this->authentication->log_error('');
            }
        }

        // Link is bad so show message
        else
        {
            $view_data['recovery_error'] = 1;

            // Log an error
            $this->authentication->log_error('');
        }

        /**
         * If form submission is attempting to change password 
         */
        if( $this->tokens->match )
        {
            $this->examples_model->recovery_password_change();
        }
    }

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_header', '', TRUE);

    echo $this->load->view( 'examples/choose_password_form', $view_data, TRUE );

    echo $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Attempt to login via AJAX
 */
public function ajax_login()
{
    $this->is_logged_in();

    $this->tokens->name = 'login_token';

    $data['javascripts'] = [
        'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'
    ];

    if( $this->authentication->on_hold === TRUE )
    {
        $data['on_hold_message'] = 1;
    }

    // This check for on hold is for normal login attempts
    else if( $on_hold = $this->authentication->current_hold_status() )
    {
        $data['on_hold_message'] = 1;
    }

    $data['final_head'] = "<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(document).on( 'submit', 'form', function(e){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'post',
                    cache: false,
                    url: '/examples/ajax_attempt_login',
                    data: {
                        'login_string': $('#login_string').val(),
                        'login_pass': $('#login_pass').val(),
                        'login_token': $('[name=\"login_token\"]').val()
                    },
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function(response){
                        $('[name=\"login_token\"]').val( response.token );
                        console.log(response);
                        if(response.status == 1){
                            $('form').replaceWith('<p>You are now logged in.</p>');
                            $('#login-link').attr('href','/examples/logout').text('Logout');
                            $('#ajax-login-link').parent().hide();
                        }else if(response.status == 0 && response.on_hold){
                            $('form').hide();
                            $('#on-hold-message').show();
                            alert('You have exceeded the maximum number of login attempts.');
                        }else if(response.status == 0 && response.count){
                            alert('Failed login attempt ' + response.count + ' of ' + $('#max_allowed_attempts').val());
                        }
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>";

    $html = $this->load->view('examples/page_header', $data, TRUE);
    $html .= $this->load->view('examples/ajax_login_form', $data, TRUE);
    $html .= $this->load->view('examples/page_footer', '', TRUE);

    echo $html;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * Test for login via ajax
 */
public function ajax_attempt_login()
{
    if( $this->input->is_ajax_request() )
    {
        // Allow this page to be an accepted login page
        $this->config->set_item('allowed_pages_for_login', ['examples/ajax_attempt_login'] );

        // Make sure we aren't redirecting after a successful login
        $this->authentication->redirect_after_login = FALSE;

        // Do the login attempt
        $this->auth_data = $this->authentication->user_status( 0 );

        // Set user variables if successful login
        if( $this->auth_data )
            $this->_set_user_variables();

        // Call the post auth hook
        $this->post_auth_hook();

        // Login attempt was successful
        if( $this->auth_data )
        {
            echo json_encode([
                'status'   => 1,
                'user_id'  => $this->auth_user_id,
                'username' => $this->auth_username,
                'level'    => $this->auth_level,
                'role'     => $this->auth_role,
                'email'    => $this->auth_email
            ]);
        }

        // Login attempt not successful
        else
        {
            $this->tokens->name = 'login_token';

            $on_hold = ( 
                $this->authentication->on_hold === TRUE OR 
                $this->authentication->current_hold_status()
            )
            ? 1 : 0;

            echo json_encode([
                'status'  => 0,
                'count'   => $this->authentication->login_errors_count,
                'on_hold' => $on_hold, 
                'token'   => $this->tokens->token()
            ]);
        }
    }

    // Show 404 if not AJAX
    else
    {
        show_404();
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------

/**
 * If you are using some other way to authenticate a created user, 
 * such as Facebook, Twitter, etc., you will simply call the user's 
 * record from the database, and pass it to the maintain_state method.
 *
 * So, you must know either the user's username or email address to 
 * log them in.
 *
 * How you would safely implement this in your application is your choice.
 * Please keep in mind that such functionality bypasses all of the 
 * checks that Community Auth does during a normal login.
 */
public function social_login()
{
    // Add the username or email address of the user you want logged in:
    $username_or_email_address = '';

    if( ! empty( $username_or_email_address ) )
    {
        $auth_model = $this->authentication->auth_model;

        // Get normal authentication data using username or email address
        if( $auth_data = $this->{$auth_model}->get_auth_data( $username_or_email_address ) )
        {
            /**
             * If redirect param exists, user redirected there.
             * This is entirely optional, and can be removed if 
             * no redirect is desired.
             */
            $this->authentication->redirect_after_login();

            // Set auth related session / cookies
            $this->authentication->maintain_state( $auth_data );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Example requires that you set a username or email address.';
    }
}

// -----------------------------------------------------------------------
}

/* End of file Examples.php */
/*



Location: /community_auth/controllers/Examples.php */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. That cause $this->require_role('admin') method in first if.